# Do YouTube captions store the timestamp of when they occur?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I had the idea to create a python script that allows you to input a music video (that has captions) and goes through the captions to blank the parts of the video which have bad language. Essentially a program that makes music clean. It, however, relies on the idea that YouTube captions have a timestamp which I can access. Also unsure of the limits on how I can manipulate the sound inside of python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do!

I am not sure how to achieve this using python though.

I have used https://www.downloadyoutubesubtitles.com/ to download the auto generated subtitles from a Youtube video.

You can try putting in the video link and download the subtitle as a SRT file

Comment: Oh that's great thanks! I'll probably look at slightly changing my plan - I may have it download the video and look at manipulating it that way whilst accessing captions. Kinda working in new territory right now so we'll see aha.